# how to issue a `start of string` pattern for ag

Tags: ag

I want to find every file in from the current dir and downwards whose filename starts with `foo` using **[`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)**(the silver searcher). I have tried:

```
ag -g '^foo' 
ag -g '\^foo' 
ag -g '\Afoo'
```

no luck.

But it should work as `ag` implements PCRE syntax, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure `echo foo*` isn't enough?

Comment: Also, possible `find ./ -type f -name "foo*" -print`

Comment: @ilkkachu, fixed question to include deep dirs.

Comment: @ThomasN, I specifically chose `ag` because it ignores patterns inside .gitignore and such, and provides me a way to match strings inside the files. With `ag` I could, for example, use -G and restrict my **grep like search** to the files that match the `^foo` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out that ag matches against the full path name of the file. So we have to change the regex in the lines of:

```
ag -g '/foo[^/]*$'
```

credits to [bmalehorn](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/952#issuecomment-239318509)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not specify a directory, and therefore search in the current directory, *ag* seems to prepend `'./'` before each path.

```
thinkbox ~% mkdir foo
thinkbox ~% cd foo
thinkbox ~/foo% touch bar
thinkbox ~/foo% ag -g '^bar' # not found            
thinkbox 1? ~/foo% ag -g '^\./bar' # found
bar
```

Comment: Indeed; this looks correct whereas the other answer says ag matches against the full path, which doesn't sound quite right.